# Dask item assignment. Cannot use loc for item assignment

Tags: python, pandas, dask, series

I have a folder of parquet files that I can't fit in memory so I am using `dask` to perform the data cleansing operations. I have a function where I want to perform item assignment but I can't seem to find any solutions online that qualify as solutions to this particular function. Below is the function that works in pandas. How do I get the same results in a dask dataframe? I thought delayed might help but all of the solutions I've tried to write haven't been working.

```
def item_assignment(df):

    new_col = np.bitwise_and(df['OtherCol'], 0b110)

    df['NewCol'] = 0
    df.loc[new_col == 0b010, 'NewCol'] = 1
    df.loc[new_col == 0b100, 'NewCol'] = -1 

    return df
```

> `TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can replace your `loc` assignments with [`dask.dataframe.Series.mask`](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.mask):

```
df['NewCol'] = 0
df['NewCol'] = df['NewCol'].mask(new_col == 0b010, 1)
df['NewCol'] = df['NewCol'].mask(new_col == 0b100, -1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `map_partitions` in this case where you can use raw pandas functionality. I.e.

```
ddf.map_partitions(item_assignment)
```

this operates on the individual pandas constituent dataframes of the dask dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"OtherCol":[0b010, 0b110, 0b100, 0b110, 0b100, 0b010]})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)
ddf.map_partitions(item_assignment).compute()
```

And we see the result as expected:

```
   OtherCol  NewCol
0         2       1
1         6       0
2         4      -1
3         6       0
4         4      -1
5         2       1
```

Comment: @MattElgazar I just tested it (see my edited answer) and it appears to work. Which parts wasn't behaving as expected?

Comment: I see - it might actually work (i'll have to dig deeper into the dataset to see if there are any issues), but the output was different possibly because my dataset is so big that .head() showed a different partition of all the data. How does the syntax of map_partitions function work with multiple arguments in a function? For example if I have def item_assignment(df, timeframe), i want ddf.map_partitions(item_assignment, ['1min']) where '1min' is the argument of the function

Comment: Yeah that should work, or use a lambda function `ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: item_assignment(df, ['1 min']))`

Comment: Ok cool - and same with multiple arguments? Like ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: item_assignment(df, ['1min', '10min']). Or just simply ddf.map_partitions(item_assignment, ['1min', '10min']. Both should work and return the same output?

Comment: You can think of the lambda as a normal function call, so depends on your function signature if you have `def my_func(df, arg1, arg2)` and you want to pass it your dataframe with arg1 as 1 and arg2 as 2 then your lambda should look like `lambda df: my_func(df, 1, 2)`

Comment: ddf.map_partitions(item_assignment, lambda df: df(ddf, '1min', '10min')) does not work. Am i missing something?

Comment: Yeah that's not quite right, maybe ask in another question as these comments are getting quite long but it would be more like `ddf.map_partitions(lambda df: item_assignment(df, '1min', '10min'))` (although your function in the original question doesn't take any optional arguments so can't validate fully). The way to think of map partitions is to think what happens to each sub-dataframe in your full ddf

Comment: Are there any downside to map_partitions?  Am I going trap myself in the small data regime if I build this into my workflow?