# Numpy where function equivalent in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I am adding a new column based on some condition on series.

I have a numpy.where statement as below:

```
df['New_Col']= np.where(df['Name']=='John', df['Class'], 'Unknown')
```

But its taking lot of time on large data, so I was trying to accomplish the same using pd.Series.apply function as:

```
df['New_Col'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda name: df['Class'] if name == 'John' else 'Unknown')
```

But its assigning whole series whenever the condition satisfy, but Ideally **I want to assign only equivalent row for that iteration**

Please let know if anyone have any input on the same, or correct me to replace the np.where with much efficient way

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mind to provide an example? In my experience `np.where` it's way faster. You can eventually create a mask and use `loc`.

Comment: How big is your data? Generally, `np.where` is slightly faster than some pandas built-in functions.

Comment: My csv size is 89GB, and I am using Dask to read and perform transformation.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for taking time and providing your valuable inputs, but I am facing error TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment  when I am using df['New_Col1'] = 'Unknown' and then df.loc[df['Name']=='John', 'New_Col1'] = df['Class']. Please note that I am using Dask

Comment: I got the solution to solve TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment, here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360549/dask-item-assignment-cannot-use-loc-for-item-assignment. Let me try and will update here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask solution:

You actually don't need to use the `where` function:

```
df['New_Col'] = df['Class'][df['Name']=='John']
```

Then fill the NaN values by the value you want:

```
df['New_Col'] = df['New_Col'].fillna('Unknown')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adreas K., I compare the speed of np.where and the approach u proposed and urs is much faster. My csv size is 74GB, and np.where took around 1111 secs and ur approach took only 0.012 sec.
Many thanks!!