# Pandas: optimise iterating with a condition on both row and column with large file

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, conditional-statements

I have the following data, and what I would like is to fill in col E with values from another row (let’s call it the target row) in col D only when the following conditions are met:

- col E has no value
- the string in col A of the target row is the same as that in col A
- the value in col B for the target row is the same as the value in col C

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XXZ | a | d | 1 |  |
| 2 | YXXZ | b | a | 2 |  |
| 3 | YXXZ | c | b | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | YXXZ | d | c | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | XXZ | e | a | 4 |  |

What I would get would be something like this:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXZ | a | d | 1 | 1 |
| YXXZ | b | a | 2 | 2 |
| YXXZ | c | b | 3 | 2 |
| YXXZ | d | c | 4 | 5 |
| XXZ | e | a | 4 | NaN |

The answer from @ralubrusto below works, but is clearly not efficient for large files. Is there any suggestion on how to make it work faster?

```
missing = df.E.isna()

for id in df[missing].index:
    original = df.loc[id]

    # Second condition
    equal_A = df[df['A'] == original['A']]

    # Third condition
    the_one = equal_A[equal_A['C'] == original['B']]

    # Assigning
    if len(the_one) > 0:
        df.at[id, 'E'] = the_one.iloc[0]['D']
```

Comment: I didnt understand your instructions at all...

Comment: I have rephrased. Is it any clearer?

Comment: What is target row?

Comment: The row from which I would like to extract the value in col D

Comment: the. Why you put on line 2, 2

Comment: I have numbered the rows to help: it is a 2 on line 2 because, C2 = B1 and D for row 1 is 2. Does that clarify?

Comment: B1 == C5,  so you copied D1 to E5, even though it should be the opposite, right? From your instructions E1 should receive D5

Comment: no, let me try to clarify the process in stages:
For a given row Y
1. select all rows with no value in col E
2. find all rows X in this subset for which Bx==Cy
3. check that Ax==Ay
4. if true apply value of Dx to Dy.
hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have multiple and different conditions, you might wanna do something like:

```
# Find missing E values
missing = df.E.isna()

for id in df[missing].index:
    original = df.loc[id]

    # Second condition
    equal_A = df[df['A'] == original['A']]

    # Third condition
    the_one = equal_A[equal_A['C'] == original['B']]

    # Assigning
    if len(the_one) > 0:
        df.at[id, 'E'] = the_one.iloc[0]['D']
```

The answer for your example data would be:

```
      A  B  C  D    E
0   XXZ  a  d  1  4.0
1  YXXZ  b  a  2  3.0
2  YXXZ  c  b  3  2.0
3  YXXZ  d  c  4  5.0
4   XXZ  e  a  4  NaN
```

*Edit*: Thanks for your patience. I've tried a few different approaches to accomplish this task, and most of them are pretty inefficient, as you can see in the `perfplot` below (it's not a perfect plot, but you can get the general idea).

[image: perfplot image]

I've tried some approaches using `groupby`, `apply`, `for` loops (the previous answer) and finally a `merge` one, which is by far the fastest one.

Here it is its code:

```
_df = (df.reset_index()
       .merge(df, left_on=['A', 'B'],
              right_on=['A', 'C'],
              how='inner',
              suffixes=['_ori', '_target']))

_df.loc[_df.E_ori.isna(), 'E_ori'] = _df.loc[_df.E_ori.isna(), 'D_target']
_df.set_index('index', inplace=True)

df.loc[_df.index, 'E'] = _df['E_ori']
```

It's really more efficient than the previous solution, so please try it out using your dataset and tell us if you have any further issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just tried your solution. I did not get an error but it has already been more than a few minutes running. Do you think it is normal for a csv under 30mb?

Comment: Indeed - I have left it all night, and it could not even go through a 1GB file. Is there a more computationally efficient way to do this?

Comment: @Alexisargentine Thanks for your patience. Please take a look at the edited answer

Comment: I have tried to implement your solution with a very big dataset (290GB) using dask, but I get the error message: `TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment`.
Per this SO thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360549/dask-item-assignment-cannot-use-loc-for-item-assignment) I know that I should use `dask.dataframe.Series.mask`instread, but I can't manage to implement it with your solution. Any idea how to do this?