# How to update a column value based on another column condition in Dask dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dask, dask-dataframe

I'm reading a 25 GB data using Dask Dataframe

Was trying to filter a column based a condition from another column and make it Nan values. In Pandas we use something like,

```py
df.loc[
    df['Reference'].str.contains(r'Ref',regex=True) == True,
    ['Reference','Ref2']
] = np.nan
```

However when trying to employ with Dask getting like,

```py
TypeError: _LocIndexer object does not support item Assignment
```

I'm new to Dask.

Comment: did you get this this to work with a smaller pandas dataframe?

Comment: Yes pandas it is fine but this is with respect to Dask dataframe. Code wise it is varying. As I'm new to dask I could not get exactly to achieve it through dask dataframe

Comment: *Code wise it is varying* -- what do you mean by that? Could you paste (as text) about 15 relevant rows and 3 columns that demonstrate this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dask item assignment. Cannot use loc for item assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54360549/dask-item-assignment-cannot-use-loc-for-item-assignment)

Comment: @PaulH - the OP is specifically asking about dask-dataframe. the `pandas` tag should be dropped. by "code wise it is varying" I assume the OP means that the pandas API is different from dask - specifically, masking a dataframe with a dask.Series using `.loc` is not supported.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I picked up on that. I was trying to figure out if they had tried something different in pandas than what was shown here.

Comment: ahh - got it. I forgot you were a dask person :)

Comment: This should do the trick I think: `df[['Reference','Ref2']] = df[['Reference','Ref2']].mask(df['Reference'].str.contains(r'Ref',regex=True))`